# Sum ranged values

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I am trying to sum the ranged values but for some reason it's not summing. Any idea why?
I am not a very good in JavaScript but I have some knowledge...

```
function bag(input) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var AllValues = sheet.getRange(input).getValues();
    var FValue = "";
    var TotalGold = 0;
    var TotalSilver = 0;
    var TotalBronze = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < AllValues.length; i++) {
        var total = AllValues[i][0].split(" ");

        for(i = 0; i < total.length; i++){
            if (total[i].indexOf("g") >= 0) {
                var value = total[i].replace("g","");
                var gold = value * 1;
                TotalGold = TotalGold + gold;
            }
            else if (total[i].indexOf("s") >= 0) {
                var value = total[i].replace("s","");
                var silver = value * 1;
                TotalSilver = TotalSilver + silver;
            }
            else if (total[i].indexOf("b") >= 0) {
                var value = total[i].replace("b","");
                var bronze = value * 1;
                TotalBronze = TotalBronze + bronze;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return TotalGold + "g " + TotalSilver + "s " + TotalBronze + "b";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are overwriting your value of `i` in the nested iteration. Pick another identifier. E.g: `for (var j = 0; j < total.length; j++) { ... }`

Comment: thanks, it's working now. I had as well to take out the else event because if there was on the range any empety cell it will return empety. By the way in the formula i need to use =bag("c5:c8") for example how can i make not need the " in formular just =bag(c5:c8)... thanks